# PHP and MYSQL "while" prints only one value

Tags: php, mysql

Hey all i have a mind bug with this wile loop , i am a bit of a noob

```
$sql_advanced_bio = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bio_details WHERE mem_id='$id'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_advanced_bio)){


$bio_time_family = $row["bio_time_family"];

}
```

So this is the php now in my HTML i have this

```
*php echo $bio_time_family *
```

**Why dose it echo only one value  ?**

**SIMPLE ANSWER**
so i tried somethingh easier like this $bio_fun_family .= $row["bio_fun_family"].",";

and then this

$bio_fun_family = substr($bio_fun_family,0,-1);

I added the .next to the =

It appends the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the values in an array, otherwise you're just overwriting one variable each time, so you'll just end up with the last value.

You also need to use a loop to echo out each value in the array.

```
$sql_advanced_bio = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bio_details WHERE mem_id='$id'");
$bio_time_family = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_advanced_bio)) {
   $bio_time_family[] = $row["bio_time_family"];
}
```

And then for the output;

```
foreach($bio_time_family as $b) {
   echo($b . '<br />');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With each iteration of the while loop, you're assigning to `$bio_time_family` the newly extracted value. If you'd like to make an array of the, instead, use `$bio_time_family[] = $row["bio_time_family"];`

Comment: zou should use `print_r($bio_time_family)`, not `echo`, when you want to visualize an array.

Answer (score 0):

Because every time you run through the loop you're re-assigning `$bio_time_family` to the next row's value. Try calling `echo` directly in your loop or add the row to an array, then loop through that and output the rows